# You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-glide

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to show around 5 fragments in an activity.On each activity I am showing the images which I am fetching from FirebaseListAdapter/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. As it is FragmentStagePagerAdapter adjacent views/Fragments will be initialized even they are not visible.If the tabs are scrolled in a fast manner (forward/backward) App is crashing with above mentioned error.I found out some similar issues on the internet but not able to fix this issue.I am also getting **You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity** error if I am starting a new activity(In activity I am showing images from firebase in a grid view) and closing it immediately(pressing the back button)
I am using following code.

```
adapt= new FirebaseListAdapter<MyClassStudent>(getActivity(), MyClassStudent.class, R.layout.mychild_grid_template, myRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(final View v, MyClassStudent model, int position) {
                final TextView uname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mychild_uname);

                final CircleImageView profileImage=(CircleImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.mychild_image);
                studRef.child(model.getUsername()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Child child=dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);
                        uname.setText(child.getUsername());
                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(child.getProfileImage()).into(profileImage);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Stack Trace:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a  Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).
                         at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
                         at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:509)
                         at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:563)
                         at com.mycompany.educareteacher.FragmentStudents$2$1.onDataChange(FragmentStudents.java:184)
                         at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.tl.zza(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.vg.zzHW(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.vm.run(Unknown Source)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ClassDetailActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4663411025690523798, timestamp=1500710706898, fatal=1}]
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3544
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=3544, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ClassDetailActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4663411025690523798}]
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mycompany.com.educareteacher, PID: 5154
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a  Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).
                      at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
                      at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:509)
                      at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:563)
                      at com.mycompany.educareteacher.FragmentStudents$2$1.onDataChange(FragmentStudents.java:184)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.tl.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.vg.zzHW(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.vm.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: I am also getting similar problem can someone help me.
[Please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718856/creating-a-blog-app-with-firebase-fragmentactivity-not-showing-images)

Answer (score 10):

Your fragment is detached before response coming from firebase, So try to check `getActivity()` null before using that

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (getActivity() == null) {
        return;
    }
    Child child = dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);
    uname.setText(child.getUsername());
    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(child.getProfileImage()).into(profileImage);
}
```

You can do like to check activity is null or not in other place.

```
private Activity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    mActivity = getActivity();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mActivity = null;
}

private void doAction() {
    if (mActivity == null) {
        return;
    }

    adapt = new FirebaseListAdapter<MyClassStudent>(mActivity, MyClassStudent.class, R.layout.mychild_grid_template, myRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(final View v, MyClassStudent model, int position) {
            final TextView uname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mychild_uname);

            final CircleImageView profileImage = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mychild_image);
            studRef.child(model.getUsername()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (mActivity == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Child child = dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);
                    uname.setText(child.getUsername());
                    Glide.with(mActivity).load(child.getProfileImage()).into(profileImage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using [isAdded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) method of fragment before loading image with Glide.

Answer (score 3):

I Found this way too

```
public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note,NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {

Context context;

public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Note model) {


    context = holder.itemView.getContext();

    holder.r_tv.setText(model.getTitle());
    Glide.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.r_iv);


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, CategoryProductActivity.class);
            MainActivity.myCategory2 = model.getTitle();
            MainActivity.myCategoryIcon2 = model.getImage();
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category,parent,false);

    return new NoteHolder(v);
}

public static class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView r_tv;
    ImageView r_iv;

    public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        r_tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.r_tv);
        r_iv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.r_iv);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Below Code on Activity on which RecyclerView is present

   ```
   public static Context context;
   ```
2. Then in `onCreate` of the same Activity on which RecyclerView is present add below Code

   ```
   context = getApplicationContext();
   ```
3. then take reference to glide as shown below

   ```
   Glide.with(YourActivity.context).load("Image Link").into(holder.YourImageView);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

in fragment just use.

```java
if (getActivity != null) { 
    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).into(yourImageView); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This problem arise when you miss to add context in the constructor of a adapter and you can easily solve it :-)**

**Do not forget to add this.context = context in the constructor**

```
public groupUserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Users> groupUsers) {
    this.groupUsers = groupUsers;
    this.context = context;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this issue. add below code in **onBindViewHolder** inside

```
context = holder.itemView.getContext();
```

Example

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Note model) {

 context = holder.itemView.getContext();

Glide.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.r_iv);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<ClientData> clientData = new ArrayList<>();
int j=0;
for (String h:profileImg)
{
    ClientData clientItem = new ClientData();
    clientItem.setProfileImage(h);
    clientItem.setName(name[j]);
    clientItem.setAddress(location[j]);
    clientData.add(clientItem);
    j++;
    }
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
    recy_client.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recy_client.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    clientAdp = new ClientAdp(getApplicationContext(),clientData);
    recy_client.setAdapter(clientAdp);
```

Replace From

```
clientAdp = new ClientAdp(context,clientData);
```

To

```
clientAdp = new ClientAdp(getApplicationContext(),clientData);
```

in my case

Comment: Please read [how to format a post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so that we are able to read and understand your answer.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].